# Execute feature file (Cucumber/SpecFlow) with parameters?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, specflow, gherkin

So i want to execute the same feature file (in SpecFlow) along with different parameters...

**Lets say** we 5 calculators and we have 10 test that test the basic abilities of calculator; 
So i want to execute the tests and just change the calculator every time.

There is such option for specifc scenario that called "Scenario Outline", it's not good for my soltion cause i have some data prepration in 'BeforeFeature' method that affect on all feature tests.
I'm also can't use in 'backround' because the data prepration take a long time so i have to do it only once before the feature execute.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can duplicate your scenarios in feature file with different parameters across scenarios. You can distinct scenarios by putting them in different feature files. These 2 options are very basics, and at the moment i can't think of any other convenient solution. Since you said you have time consuming data preparation in before feature hook, then i suggest you to introduce duplication of scenarios inside existing feature file. There is no specflow feature which allows you to do what you asked. It's all about to recognize the possibilities and constraints, and work on suitable trade-offs.

Comment: Are you asking how to execute a feature with parameters, or are you actually asking how to perform data preparation only once before a scenario is run? You appear to be asking two questions.

Comment: Greg Burghardt
I'm asking the first option...

Comment: Stefan Zivkovic
Yeah, this was my solution for meanwhile... but i'm looking for more elegant solution...

Comment: @elhananShir Do you want something to persist during the whole feature? If yes, you can use `FeatureContext`